# How does java.ext.dirs support multiple directories

Tags: java, configuration, command-line-interface, classloader, library-path

When I run a Java JAR with the parameter `-Djava.ext.dirs=xxx` it works, but it could not find security libraries which are provided by `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`. Does `java.ext.dirs` support multiple directories?

Comment: I found multiple directories can be separated with ":", like directorA:directB .

Answer (score 2):

Use the colon as the delimiter on Mac OSX and Unix/Linux:

```
dirA:dirB:dirC
```

Use the semicolon as the delimiter on Windows:

```
dirA;dirB;dirC
```

**References**

- [TechNotes: Windows Java Launcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)
- [TechNotes: Unix Java Launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)